# Limits with IN operator

Tags: where

Are there any upper limits on the amount of terms that could be between the parenthesis on an IN operator?

For example, the query would look something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE number IN (1,2,3...n)
```

I'm curious if there's any upper limit for 'n'.

Comment: As soon as I published this, I realized the title probably is terrible, but can't think of a way to word it more clearly. If anyone has any better ideas, please update accordingly. Also, I left out SQL version, since I'm looking for a more broad answer that may apply to all (or most) SQL types as a whole.

Comment: You'll need to look at the implemention of your particular RDBMS!

Comment: As @Vérace said, it depends on the platform used.

Comment: @Salmononius2 Could you please update the question and tags with which DMBS platform you are, specifically, asking about?

Comment: Oh, yeah, almost forgot. Some (all?) implementations have limits on the size of the actual SQL (64k?) you can send, so if you had 5000 numbers, you might be OK, but if you had 5000 VARCHAR(100)'s - you might be bunched! Put them into the a table and `JOIN`. Secondly, if you are running up against these kind of theoretical limits, you should look at your design - they are limits, not targets!

Comment: @Vérace: Postgres and Oracle do not have a hard limit on the size of a single SQL query.

Answer (score 2):

You mean the IN operator. There are limits, but they differ from DB engine to engine.

- SQL Server: 65,536 * Network Packet Size - [see Batch Size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server)
- [Oracle seems to allow 1,000.](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_maximum_number_of_sql_in_list_values.htm)

Comment: Worth noting MS warn against using large lists ("many thousands") whic you could reach before hitting the batch size limit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql

Comment: @GarethLyons Good point.

Comment: Wes your 1st link is broken